# Data modeling for employees with manager's record updated weekly

Tags: database-design, table

I would like a best practice or some direction on how to handle employee data, as I just took ownership of the database management

The table employee looks like this

| id | employee | manager | week | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | Don | 22 | 10 |
| 2 | jeff | Don | 22 | 8 |
| 3 | fred | Don | 22 | 7 |

It's updated weekly, because we track performance weekly and that counts towards the manager's performance.

Next week, an employee could have a different manager and performance will count towards that new manager

| id | employee | manager | week | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | john | Don | 23 | 10 |
| **5** | **jeff** | **Robert** | **23** | **9.2** |
| 6 | fred | Don | 23 | 7 |

The company has 500 employees and we have 52 weeks in a year, so imagine how big that table is. Is there any recommendation or a best practice to track weekly performance and avoid repeated data in the same table?

Comment: I think I'll keep it like that then. I refer as repetitive like having 20 employees under the same manager during 6 months, I would repeat their registry 24 times and I'd just change the week number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance perspective, 500 * 52 = only 26,000 records added per year, so this is a tiny amount of data that you have to support and if it only changes weekly it's not very busy sounding either.

If performance is the context for your question, I wouldn't worry about it at all. - [user150011](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150011/j-d)

This table can't be reduced significantly. You can log only weeks where management has been changed for certain employee but this approach requires a lot more complicated code to deal with. – [user7895](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7895/kondybas)